# Shorting the output of both the channels of L298N

Tags: motor, dc-motor, h-bridge, motor-controller, high-current

Suppose I started with a project requiring the control of motors and ended with using L298N in my project, realizing that my motor only takes around 1.5A when on load.
Now, with time I realized that my motors be more powerful for the application I was making my project and hence, I changed my motors. Now with that my motors were now taking around 2.5A when on load.
But since each channel of L298N can only provide maximum of 2A when properly heat compensated, I thought of shorting both the out pins of both the channels (one pin to one output and another to another). This will eventually make the allowable current to 4A but I believe there might be some issues that I might face in the long run.
Could anyone help me point out any of the issues that I might face?

PS: I have done this tinkering because there is an urgent requirement from the client of the product and I don't have enough time to change my core architecture. But eventually, I have been working on shifting to mosfet based H-bridge driver, which I know will not pose me much issue of current demand.

Comment: What is your motor DCR , supply voltage , heatsink thermal reistance?

Comment: What does DCR mean?
And as for supply voltage, L298 is being supplied from 13.6V (output of 150W booster), and aluminium thermal heat sink is used for cooling purpose.

Comment: DCR is the DC resistance coil spec used for motors and inductors.